# Delete handled by resource controller doesn't work - Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, controller

I'm using resource controller in Laravel 5.3 and I'm having problem with deleting a record. I would like to use simple HTML code and I know that I have to add a hidden method input to make it work.

My code is very simple:

```
<form action="{{ url('/task', $task->id) }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

After clicking submit app redirects to blank page - it doesn't go to destroy function in controller. I don't have any idea, why it's not working. I'm not using facades, is it necessary in operation like this? I'll be very glad for every tip, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're most likely running into a `TokenMismatchException`. Laravel considers the `DELETE` method a "writable" method, so it expects a CSRF token.

You can either add a CSRF token to your form, or, if appropriate, you can add your URI to the `except` array in your `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` file.

To add the token to your form:

```
<form action="{{ url('/task', $task->id) }}">
    {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you very much @patricus. I think there is still problem with DELETE method - now it's redirecting me to **show** action with link: http://localhost:8000/task/1?_method=DELETE&_token=cVhSr7ZTHfBXg0vQNyyyfjBUGG1Xp5rJXgg59LPO

The URI for destroy and show actions are the same but my app seems to use bad method for this request.

Comment: Problem fixed. I've added a **method="POST"** to the form tag and with csrf field it's working well now. Thank you!